# AWS cognito user pools, custom message lambda

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, lambda

Good day to everyone.

I have a problem with AWS cognito user pools custom message which is created inside lambda function as a trigger (custom message lambda). Message with verification link inside. In particular I'm setting message subject to "Custom subject" (and email has this subject), and message body to "Use this {##Custom link##} instead" (and the message is not appear in the body, but the one from user pools web interface is used).

My code is:

```
public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException {
    JsonNode json = parseJsonFromStream(input);
    ObjectNode jsonWithResponse = (ObjectNode) json;
    jsonWithResponse.with("response").put("emailMessage", "Use this {##Custom link##} instead");
    jsonWithResponse.with("response").put("emailSubject", "Custom subject");
    try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8")) {
            w.write(jsonWithResponse.toString());
    }
}
```

I had tried to set even {####} instead {##Link text##} and still same. I'm almost sure it worked some time ago (and I don't remember I changed anything). Does anyone has any idea where should I take a look (dig). As I spent too much time on that and neither missing something (hopefully) small or they have some changes/issues.

P.S. lambda test success. Lambda output looks fine (I eliminate logger here).

Upd: (logger output with response)

```
OUTPUT JSON is
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "userPoolId": "****",
    "userName": "*****",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-android-2.6.7",
        "clientId": "****"
    },
    "triggerSource": "CustomMessage_SignUp",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "sub": "****",
            "email_verified": "false",
            "cognito:user_status": "UNCONFIRMED",
            "nickname": "Yaroslav",
            "email": "****"
        },
        "codeParameter": "{####}",
        "usernameParameter": null
    },
    "response": {
        "emailMessage": "Use this {##Custom link##} instead",
        "emailSubject": "Custom subject"
    }
}
```

Upd2 (JS trigger):

I added code on js (new trigger for custom email) based on [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-examples.html#aws-lambda-triggers-custom-message-example) and that works for custom email when user wants confirmation code, but that doesn't work for confirmation link. Again, I tried {##link##} for the link.

Comment: Check the lambda Cloudwatch logs? Is the lambda invoked? Are there any errors? Try logging jsonWithResponse just before writing it to stream.

Comment: Lambda is invoked, no errors is there. Response I had added to UPD section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up with is to use code confirmation. In this case custom email works as expected.

To prevent the user from typing the password into the app, I sent email with custom link, which include the code parametr. Custom link pointed to API Gateway which had corresponding lambda to handle everything and finish the user registration.