# Unable to overcome InvalidLambdaResponseException for Java AWS Lambda Cognito custom message trigger

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I keep getting an `InvalidLambdaResponseException` with a message saying "Unrecognizable lambda output" whenever I try to use a custom message trigger when creating a new account in cognito. The lambda trigger is written in java and I have had trouble finding documentation or an example for how to write a cognito trigger in java. The best I could find is this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526687/aws-lambda-response-in-java-for-cognito) which enabled me to figure out how to format the output message properly yet the exception is still being thrown. I understand from looking over the JavaScript examples you must return the event received or an object with the same parameter format, which I am attempting to do with no avail. Below you will find the input and output I receive as logged by cloud watch. What am I doing wrong?

This is the raw input

```
{version=1, region=us-east-1, userPoolId=*****,
userName= *****, callerContext={awsSdkVersion=aws-sdk-nodejs-2.166.0, 
clientId=*****}, triggerSource=CustomMessage_SignUp,
request={userAttributes={custom:position_group=["All"],
sub=*****, email_verified=false, cognito:user_status=UNCONFIRMED, 
given_name=*****, custom:permissions=, custom:team_id=*****,
email=*****@gmail.com}, codeParameter={####},usernameParameter=null}, 
response={smsMessage=null, emailMessage=null, emailSubject=null}}
```

And here is the output

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "triggerSource": "CustomMessage_SignUp",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "userPoolId": "*****",
    "userName": "*****",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-nodejs-2.166.0",
        "clientId": "*****"
    },
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "userAttributes": {
                "custom:position_group": "[\"All\"]",
                "sub": "*****",
                "email_verified": "false",
                "cognito:user_status": "UNCONFIRMED",
                "given_name": "*****",
                "custom:permissions": "",
                "custom:team_id": "*****",
                "email": "*****@gmail.com"
            },
            "codeParameter": "{####}"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "smsMessage": "{####} is your verification code.",
        "emailMessage": "TEST {####}",
        "emailSubject": "Verification"
        } 
}
```

**Addition**
After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471904/aws-cognito-user-pools-custom-message-lambda?rq=1) I tried switching my handler method to this

```
public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(input);
        logger.log(mapper.writeValueAsString(json));
        ObjectNode jsonWithResponse = (ObjectNode) json;
        jsonWithResponse.with("response").put("smsMessage", "TEST {####}");
        jsonWithResponse.with("response").put("emailMessage", "TEST {####}");
        jsonWithResponse.with("response").put("emailSubject", "TEST subject");
        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8")) {
                w.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonWithResponse));
        }
        logger.log(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonWithResponse));
    }
```

which out puts this in cloud watch before

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "userPoolId": "*****",
    "userName": "*****",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-nodejs-2.166.0",
        "clientId": "*****"
    },
    "triggerSource": "CustomMessage_SignUp",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "custom:position_group": "[\"All\"]",
            "sub": "*****",
            "email_verified": "false",
            "cognito:user_status": "UNCONFIRMED",
            "given_name": "*****",
            "custom:permissions": "",
            "custom:team_id": "*****",
            "email": "*****@gmail.com"
        },
        "codeParameter": "{####}",
        "usernameParameter": null
    },
    "response": {
        "smsMessage": null,
        "emailMessage": null,
        "emailSubject": null
    }
}
```

and this in cloud watch after

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "userPoolId": "*****",
    "userName": "*****",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-nodejs-2.166.0",
        "clientId": "*****"
    },
    "triggerSource": "CustomMessage_SignUp",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "custom:position_group": "[\"All\"]",
            "sub": "*****",
            "email_verified": "false",
            "cognito:user_status": "UNCONFIRMED",
            "given_name": "*****",
            "custom:permissions": "",
            "custom:team_id": "*****",
            "email": "*****@gmail.com"
        },
        "codeParameter": "{####}",
        "usernameParameter": null
    },
    "response": {
        "smsMessage": "TEST  {####}",
        "emailMessage": "TEST {####}",
        "emailSubject": "TEST subject"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you still have this InvalidLambdaResponseException? (i.e. do you still need some help here, or it's solved?)

Comment: I figured it out, I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to the fact that I was not adding in the `{username}` key into my email response messages (smsMessage and emailMessage). Being sure to add the key `{####}` and `{username}` solved it.

Comment: If you're adding  {####} (for email), what would be the link text? I mean that we have template (on aws) which shows that we have to include {##LinkText##} in case of email, but not {####}.

Comment: I was not using a link for verification, I was sending a verification code to the user. We didnt want to show the user their username as it is a UUID that means nothing to them, so we hide it in the welcome email. (I wanted to use a verification link but at the time there was no documentation on how to do so. You guys have since updated your documentation and will take a look)

Comment: That was my problem. It does work when I'm using the code, but doesn't work with the link verification. And the doc didn't help. So if you manage to work custom email with confirmation link somehow - please update me.